# How to fetch from a different origin and include cookies in the request

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, bun, elysiajs

The problem is that i went to fetch cookies from my backend thats on a different origin than my front end. And i cant get cors to work with me. I am using bun with elysia.

This is an example i made to narrow down the problem.

The front end will create two cookies that i want to pas the backend. Then they get noted and create a new cookie and send it to the front end. This works if the orgin is the same. So if you go to localhost 1234 and create username and password cookies yourself in the developer tools it works
as intended.

I have tried including the header'Content-Type': 'application/json' and credentials: "include" in the fetch.

**Backend**

```
import Elysia from "elysia";
import cors from "@elysiajs/cors";

const app = new Elysia();

app.use(cors());

app.post("/cookies", ({ cookie: { username, password, icecream } }) => {
    icecream.value = "chocolate";
    console.log(username + ":" + password);
});

app.listen(1234);
console.log("Server up and running at http://localhost:1234");
```

**Frontend**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="password">
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("submitting");
            document.cookie = `username=${document.querySelector("input[name='username']").value}`;
            document.cookie = `password=${document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value}`;

            fetch("http://localhost:1234/cookies", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                credentials: "include"
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
        })

        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well step 1 would probably be "Get CORS to work." What exactly is the problem? What have you tried server-side to enable CORS headers?

Comment: this is the error -- Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:1234/cookies' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. And on the doc cross origin access  should be on by default. However the fetch dont go through.

Comment: https://elysiajs.com/plugins/cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/elysiajs/elysia-cors/issues/48

Thanks to gcraig-kaiza on github

You need to add this

```
  .onAfterHandle(({ request, set }) => {
    // Only process CORS requests
    if (request.method !== "OPTIONS") return;

    const allowHeader = set.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"];
    if (allowHeader === "*") {
      set.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] =
        request.headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Headers") ?? "";
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering CORS issues when trying to make a request from your frontend to your backend, which are hosted on different origins.First, you need to set up CORS on your backend
In your backend code, ensure that CORS is correctly configured to allow requests from your frontend origin. You're already using the @elysiajs/cors middleware, but you need to specify the allowed origin in your CORS configuration.
You can do this by passing an options object to the cors() function

```
import Elysia from "elysia";
import cors from "@elysiajs/cors";

const app = new Elysia();

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost: 1234"
}));
```

Then ensure credentials are included in the fetch request

```
fetch("http://localhost:1234/cookies", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: "include"
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

If your frontend and backend are hosted on different origins, the browser may first send a preflight OPTIONS request to check if the server allows the actual request. Make sure your backend responds correctly to OPTIONS requests with the appropriate CORS headers.

For example, you can add a route handler to respond to OPTIONS requests with the necessary CORS headers
`app.options("*", cors());`
This will respond to all OPTIONS requests with the appropriate CORS headers, allowing the browser to proceed with the actual request.

With these changes, your frontend should be able to make requests to your backend without encountering CORS issues. Make sure to replace `http://localhost:YOUR_FRONTEND_PORT` with the actual origin of your frontend application

Comment: [Temporary policy notice, if applicable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)

Comment: Dis did not work. Tryde `cors({
        origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
    })` and  `cors({
        origin: "true",
    })` and `app.options("*", cors());` however on the doc * is the default https://elysiajs.com/plugins/cors